# What was it Lex Luthor wanted Lois to say?

Tags: dialogue, superman-returns

In Superman Returns, Lex Luthor had... something he wanted Lois to say.

> Lex: Come on, let me hear you say it just once, come on.
>   Lois: You're insane.
>   Lex: No! *laugh* Not that, no, the other thing. I know it's just dangling off the tip of your tongue. Let me hear it just once, please?
>   Lois: Superman will never--
>   Lex: WRONG!

Everybody else knows that scene for Lex's "WRONG!" but it bugs me just what Lex wanted Lois to say. Does anyone know, or is that never stated?

Comment: I'm guessing it's "He'll never let you get away with it". Both it and "You're insane" are common things said to villains after they reveal their diabolical plan. But I'm not basing this on anything other than a hunch.

Answer (score 4):

The scene seems pretty much self explanatory. Lex is a typical egotistical villain, who believes himself to be smarter than everybody. Including Superman. And he wants nothing more than to gloat over it. He wanted Lois to say **Superman will stop you** just so he can explain to her how wrong (he thinks) she is. The very next thing he does after yelling **WRONG** is to dramatically  pull out the Kryptonite Crystal Cylinder, and waits for it to click into her head. Just so he can show he's smarter, so smart that Superman's brute force won't stop him. She said exactly what he wanted her to say.

Comment: I believe cde is right more or less, but she was going to say something like "Superman will never let you do this."